# Define and load custom eloquent relationship eagerly - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a Model called: `Client` and another one called `PaymentMethod`:

And I need to make relationship between them

So Client should has many payment methods:

In my case I want to make the binding between theses model with 2 conditions:

1 - The client_id on the payment method should be the same on the client's id (client_id == id)

2 - OR the `client_id == "all"`

condition of binding : `client_id == id OR client_id == "all"`

My question is how to define this relationship in my Client Model and make it loaded eagerly

The Structure of my database's tables

[image]

Comment: To make a relation the 2 cols need to be the same type, so mixing ids an strings is not possible for a foreign key

Comment: This is just an example to explain my situation u can take in mind any other example that require 2 conditions to make the binding between 2 models

Comment: You can't do it with client_id. Other conditions might work depending on the columns.

Comment: It's not possible to do using Laravel relationships because result of the second query get associated with the Client model using client_id. What you can do is fetch those separately and inject using [setRelation](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_setRelation) method

Comment: @RavishaHesh Can please u provide me an example of using setRelation

Comment: `$clients = Client::with('payment_methods')->get(); 
if (true) { 
 $paymentMethods = PaymentMethod::where('client_id', 'all')->get(); 
 $clients->map(function ($client) use ($paymentMethods) { 
  return $client->setRelation('payment_methods', $paymentMethods->merge($client->payment_methods)); 
 }); 
}
`